# How can we use elastic search in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, elasticsearch

I have eclipse kepler installed in my system. I have downloaded and unzipped elastic search server. Tough for java program we need jars. I downloaded some jars related to elasticsearch. Though I donno how to use elasticsearch with eclipse. Please help me with a step by step guide.i got fed up with github. I dont even know wat is github all links points yo github. So if its the only way help me out how to use github.
Looking forward for a best answer so that I can start moving with my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `libs` folder of the server has everything you need.

Comment: My elasticsearch.bat fails to run. What may be the reason.